# How to display django queryset values in templates using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-templates

I am trying to display list of names from a django queryset using , Here is my code

```
def vfunc(request):
    context={}
    bats = Bat.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    context['bats'] = bats
    [each.batname for each in bats] # Gives all the batnames. 
    return render(request, 'bat.html', context)
```

I want to display batnames on template

```
$(function() {
//This works when I hardcode the values
    var batData =  [{
            "bat":"batname1", //hardcoded & displayed in 1st row
        },  {
            "bat":"batname2", //hardcoded & displayed in 2nd row
        }];
        $("#CleanDatasNames").dxDataGrid({
            dataSource: batData,
            ...
            ...
            }
```

I am tried something like var batData = [{"bat":"{{bats|join:', ' }}"] but it is displaying obj1,obj2 in same row,I also tried to loop through but failed , any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you can work with js:

```
$(function() {
//This works when I hardcode the values
    var batData =  [
{% for bat in bats %}  
{
            "bat":"{{bat}}", 
}
{% if forloop.counter != bats|length %} // dynamically checking for last element
    , 
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
];
        $("#CleanDatasNames").dxDataGrid({
            dataSource: batData,
            ...
            ...
            }
```

Comment: This is a great help, thanks a lot @Jafoor

Comment: 1 qoubt, please explaing the if condition forloop.counter , is it necessary?

Comment: generally, we don't use `,` the last element. Javascript may not bother with `,` if you use it or not. But for clean and perfect code you can use it.